# Interpretation coefficient for summary interaction variables in lm()

Tags: r, lm

In R with multiple regression lm() function , I have 2 interrogations:

1. I want all interactions between 3 variables A, B and C (brute force interactions search) : ( A and B) + (B and A) + (A and C) + (C and A) + (B and C) + (B and C). What's the syntax for all interactions?
   Do I write:

   ```
   lm(Y~ A * B * C)
   ```

   Or

   ```
   lm(Y~ (A + B + C) * (A + B + C))
   ```

   ?
2. I don't understand how build the final regression equation with coefficient associated to interactioned variables.
   For example for this output for summary:

Please consider this summary for interactions variables with lm

```
#(Intercept) 0.97849 0.02865 34.15 <2e-16 *** 
#f1High 3.00306 0.04052 74.11 <2e-16 *** 
#f2B -1.97878 0.04052 -48.83 <2e-16 *** 
#f1High:f2B 0.98924 0.05731 17.26 <2e-16 ***
```

Is the final equation will be?
Y = 0.97 + 3 * f1High -1.97 f2B -1.97 * f2B + 0.98 * f1High * f2B ? – Theo75 24 mins ago

Thanks a lot.
Théo.

Comment: 1. Are you only interested in first order interactions? Then use option B. Are you also interested in second order interactions (i.e., `A:B:C`)? Then use option A. 2. I don't see an interaction in the example output. In fact, this output seems to be created by a different stats software than R. It appears to include a quadratic term.

Comment: Thanks. 1) Sorry but I dont' know what are  first or second order interactions. I want all interactions between A, B and C (brute force  interactions search) : ( A and B) + (B and A) + (A and C) + (C and A) +  (B and C) + (B and C). Does interactions ( A and B) and  ( B and A) are symetrics and it's not necessarry to write all combinations? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I can't read the output in your comment. Please edit your question to add the output in a formatted way.

Comment: First-order interactions are interactions between two effects. Second-order interactions are interactions between three effects. Your comment lists only first-order interactions. And yes, (A and B) and (B and A) are the same interaction that is modeled as `alpha_ab * a * b` where `alpha_ab` is the coefficient.

Comment: There is one `-1.97 f2B` too many in your equation. Furthermore, `f1` and `f2` appear to be factor (categorical) variables that have been dummy encoded (probably using treatment contrasts). It's important to understand what that means.